# Find the whole digits of a given number

Tags: java

```
int value = 456702; 
do 
{
    digit = value % 10;
    value = value / 10;
    System.out.println(digit); //I just want to get...2,0,7,6,5,4
} while (digit > 0);
```

I have tried it but it doesn't work well since when it gets digit 0 it exits from the loop.

I just want to find and retrieve digits of a given number.

E.g. 256387, I need the digits involved in this number independently, i.e. 7,8,3,6,5,2, and I have tried it. My code works well for a number that has no zeros. How can I know I reached the last digit (for example from left to right)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace condition in `while (digit > 0)` to `(value > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Take this :-

```
String s = String.valueOf(123456);
for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--) System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
```

Comment: Uugh. So much slower. Conversion to string is expensive.

Comment: yeah 0.001 ms slower -_- @Bathsheba

Comment: yeah sorry..actually I meant the number only..editted

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into string and re print from backwards

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you check whether `digit` is still larger than zero, rather than checking whether your `value` is still larger than zero. This means that you indeed stop when you encounter a digit that is zero. The following code should work though:

```
int value = 456702; 
do {
    digit = value % 10;
    value = value / 10;
    System.out.println(digit);
} while (value > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 456702; 
        int digit=0;
        do
        {
            digit = value % 10;
            value = value / 10;
            if(value!=0)
            System.out.print(digit+","); //i just want to get...2,0,7,6,5,4
            else
                System.out.print(digit);
        } while (value > 0);

    }
```

Works fine and good luck.

Gives as 2,0,7,6,5,4